# Auth0: Invalid access token payload, JWT encrypted with A256GCM algorithm

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, vuejs3, auth0

I'm trying to set up a Vue3 SPA with a NestJS API in the back. I set up my Auth0 tenant and client to integrate with the SPA and plan to send the resulting JWTs to my API. In my SPA, I use the [vue-auth0-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-auth0-plugin), which uses [@auth0/auth0-spa-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-spa-js) under the hood.

I have successfully set up the Auth Code with PKCE flow, up to the point where I receive id, access and refresh tokens. However, something is wrong with the access token and I cannot understand why it is happening. The payload is invalid JSON and the token contains 2 consecutive `.`. When I paste the token into jwt.io, the header is decoded as follows:

```json
{
  "alg": "dir",
  "enc": "A256GCM",
  "iss": "https://xyz.auth0.com/"
}
```

I would be expecting:

```json
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "w1-e..."
}
```

I have not enabled JWT encryption as far as I know (I used the wizard to set up the SPA client), could anyone point out to me what I am missing? For the sake of completeness, this is the format of my auth request:

```
https://xyz.auth0.com/authorize
    ?client_id=REq...
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1337
    &scope=openid%20profile%20email
    &response_type=code
    &response_mode=query
    &state=a2...
    &nonce=bT...
    &code_challenge=GjSw...
    &code_challenge_method=S256
    &auth0Client=eyJu...
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be an encrypted cookie returned to the front end, in an access token format. Same issue here - not sure why they call it an access token: https://community.auth0.com/t/token-in-appsession-cookie-cannot-be-decoded/60591/5. I think you are meant to send this to APIs via a back end that decrypts it to get access tokens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Gary said, the token is in JWE format. According to [this Auth0 community post](https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-access-token-is-missing-the-jws-payload/71674/5), the solution to the missing payload is to provide an `audience` parameter. You should be able to include that parameter in the query string to [the `/authorize` endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authorization-code-flow).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is not clearly mentioned in their (starter) docs. Defining an API and using that identifier as the audience, does indeed return a JWT as one would expect

Comment: HOLY CRAP this saved me after many hours of troubleshooting how to get auth0 working in Azure API management